# SSR with inertiajs 1.0 and ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, inertiajs

How to **SSR** with **inertiajs** and **ruby on rails**.

I have looked at the code of a rails template https://github.com/ElMassimo/inertia-rails-ssr-template to make SSR work but I can't make it to work. Any help will be great!. Right now we're using svelte with inertiajs and it's been great but we would like to use SSR for some pages.

Comment: "can't make it to work" -- is not useful for helping. Do you get errors? What is the behavior you are seeing? What does the code you have tried look like?

Comment: Basically it doesn't work. I have no errors or logs to show. I deploy with capistrano and I have added a task for that that runs bin/vite build --ssr

Comment: As I see there is no need to add that step into capistrano because rake assets:precompile adds bin/vite build --ssr